# Read specific value from JSON in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, json-deserialization

So I have a `JSON` string where I just want to read a specific value. How do I just pick "`Read me please!`" from string below?

```
var readString = /*Read me please!*/
```

**JSON string:**

```
"{\"aString\":\"Read me please!\"}"
```

For better understanding, how do I do the same here? (just "`Read me please!`"):

```
"{\"Result\":
    {    
    \"aString\":\"Read me please!\",
    \"anotherString\":\"Dont read me!\"
    }    
}"
```

If both alternative have different solution I would like to know both.

**PS:** I do not wish to save the value into object/class or so. Just temporary inside `var readString`.

Comment: if you know the value, why do you need to read it? unless you are looking to search a json file for user input? You need to attempt to solve this first, and post what you have tried. SO is not here to just write your code for you

Comment: @Takarii I guess read was a wrong word in my question. I want to retrieve `Read me please!` from json string into `var readString = `

Comment: Have a look at http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could write a model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string AString { get; set; }
}
```

and then use a JSON serializer such as [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
string readString = "{\"aString\":\"Read me please!\"}";
MyModel model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(readString);
Console.WriteLine(model.AString);
```

If you don't want to use third party solutions you could use the built-in [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```
string readString = "{\"aString\":\"Read me please!\"}";
MyModel model = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<MyModel>(readString);
Console.WriteLine(model.AString);
```

Now assuming you want to handle your second JSON string you could simply adapt your model:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public MyModel Result { get; set; }
}

public class MyModel
{
    public string AString { get; set; }
    public string AnotherString { get; set; }
}
```

and then deserialize to this wrapper class:

```
string readString = ... the JSON string in your second example ...;
Wrapper wrapper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wrapper>(readString);
Console.WriteLine(wrapper.Result.AString);
Console.WriteLine(wrapper.Result.AnotherString);
```

---

UPDATE:

And if you don't want to deserialize to a model you could directly do this:

```
string readString = "{\"aString\":\"Read me please!\"}";
var res = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(readString);
Console.WriteLine(res.Value<string>("aString"));
```

or with the built-in `JavaScriptSerializer` class:

```
string readString = "{\"aString\":\"Read me please!\"}";
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var res = (IDictionary<string, object>)serializer.DeserializeObject(readString);
Console.WriteLine(res["aString"]);
```

Comment: Is it possible to read JSON without deserialize it into object/model? I just want to read the value temporary.

Comment: @user7399041, yes it is possible, I will update my answer to show you how.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - won't your updated answer still deserialize the whole object?  I think you'd have to use a `JsonReader` directly to avoid that... This could be relevant if OP wants to avoid loading a potentially large object fully into memory.

Comment: @DanField, yes this will load the whole JSON in memory and tokenize it. It's a bit more efficient than deserializing to a strong model but you are correct that if absolute efficiency is required then the `JsonReader` as shown in your answer is the correct approach.

Answer (score 2):

```
var readString = JObject.Parse(str)["aString"];
```

Or for your second example:

```
var readString2 = JObject.Parse(str2)["Result"]["aString"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Json.NET also provides a JSON reader if you don't want to deserialize the whole thing.  For example:

```
string json = "{\"Result\":     {         \"aString\":\"Read me please!\",     \"anotherString\":\"Dont read me!\"     }            }";

using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json)))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName && (string)reader.Value == "aString")
        {
            reader.Read();
            Console.Write(reader.Value);
            break;
        }

    }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Newtonsoft (JSON.NET) to accomplish that. Then, you can access your json property this way:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(yourJson);
Console.WriteLine(obj.Result.aString);
```

Comment: You don't _have_ to, however you CAN to make life easier. There exists a built in version within c# already (just less user friendly)

Answer (score 0):

I played around with writing a generic method that can read any part of my json string. I tried a lot of the answers on this thread and it did not suit my need. So this is what I came up with. I use the following method in my service layer to read my configuration properties from the json string.

```
    public T getValue<T>(string json,string jsonPropertyName)
    {                      
        var parsedResult= JObject.Parse(json);

        return parsedResult.SelectToken(jsonPropertyName).ToObject<T>();
    }
```

and this is how you would use it :

```
    var result = service.getValue<List<string>>(json, "propertyName");
```

So you can use this to get specific properties within your json string and cast it to whatever you need it to be.